# Keyboard in SFML - C++

Tags: sfml

I am doing my project game, but i stuck with these codes.

```
while (window.pollEvent(e1))
    {
        if (e1.type == Event::Closed) window.close();
        if (e1.type == Event::KeyReleased)
            if (e1.key.code == Keyboard::Up) { menu.MoveUp(); break; }
            else if (e1.key.code == Keyboard::Down) { menu.MoveDown(); break; }
            else if (e1.key.code == Keyboard::Return)
            {...}
```

I made these codes for making my game menu, but when i press up and down, nothing happen. By the way this is the code for MoveUp()

```
void Menu::MoveUp()
{
    if (selectedItemIndex - 1 >= 0)
    {
        menu[selectedItemIndex].setColor(Color::White);
        selectedItemIndex--;
        menu[selectedItemIndex].setColor(Color::Red);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you're starting at `selectedItemIndex` at `0` and changing it to `-1`? The code you show seems to look fine, despite using `switch(event.type)` probably being the more elegant approach

Comment: Everything looks fine to me, other then the breaks in your if statements, and what Mario said, however I am unsure if that could cause the problem you are having(the breaks), normally you want to poll all the events every frame, by doing your break you are telling it to stop after that 1 event.  Can you possibly show us your whole loop? and show us your menu class?